# Cannot turn off Caps Lock on lock screen

Tags: greeter

Occasionally my son hits the keyboard and presses Caps Lock while the computer is locked. When I try to login I cannot. I try to turn off the Caps Lock but it's not working, the light indicator on the button is always turned on. I'm not sure if it matters but I am using Apple Aluminium Keyboard. The only solution to login is to restart the computer.
I am not really sure how I can debug this issue, but when I Ctrl+Alt+1 I see that the Caps Lock is not turned on when trying to type my username.

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting `CTRL + ALT + F1` to switch to TTY1 and then hit the caps lock key to see if it lets you change it then. If that works you can log back in by hitting `CTRL + ALT + F7` on your keyboard.

If that doesn't work, there is something else you can try. I was having a lot of issues and kernel panic problems with some of the recent Linux 4.4.x kernels that were being pushed through updates. Updating to kernel 4.8.x fixed pretty much all of them. To update your kernel try the following:

`sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 -y`

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: I've already tried the trick with going to TTY1, but it didn't work. Updating the kernel seems to fix the issue. If my Caps-Lock is turned on and I lock the session it is automatically turned off. If I press it on the lock screen it toggles properly (the led light is not turning on, but that's not an issue).

Comment: Excellent! Glad we got it fixed for you!

Comment: It turns out the problem is not fixed, just occurring less often.